# Joining tables, getting Object Reference Not Set

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm converting an existing program to MVC5, and I need to join multiple tables from a database. I made a dummy project project to experiment so I don't irreparably damage anything, and I have it successfully pulling and showing all the individual tables of the database. However, when I try to join them, I get "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Note: Products and tasks are existing models and tables in the DB. It's already deployed and we can't alter them.

Relevant controller code:

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        _db.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
        var JoinTest = (
            from a in _db.Task.AsEnumerable()
            join b in _db.Product on a.ProductId equals b.ProductId
            select new
            {
                TaskId = a.TaskId,
                TaskDesc = a.TaskDescription,
                ProdDesc = b.ProductDescription
            });
        ViewData["CompositeData"] = JoinTest;
        ViewData["ProductData"] = _db.Product.ToList();
    }
```

View code:

```
@foreach (var item in ViewData["CompositeData"] as List<TomFoolery.Models.ViewModel>)
    {
    //Printing relevant items from DB
    }
```

And, to be thorough, the definition of ViewModel:

```
namespace TomFoolery.Models
    {
        public class ViewModel
        {
            public Product Product { get; set;}
            public Task Task { get; set; }
        }
    }
```

So, where am I going wrong?

Comment: Isn't it also a problem that  JoinTest variable ( IQueryble<> ) is passed to the view. Even if   toList() is called on that variable while rendering the view , _db  is probably  disposed  because the controller is disposed. Just wanted to note that, may be related to the problem. Needs some lifecycle dig-in to verify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ViewData["CompositeData"] as List<TomFoolery.Models.ViewModel>` will return null because the items you set to `ViewData["CompositeData"]`  is a list of anonymous type.

You should create a view model and use that.

```
 public class MyViewModel
 {
     public int TaskId  {set;get;}
     public string TaskDesc {set;get;}
     public string ProductDesc {set;get;}
 }
```

and use it in your projection part.

```
ViewData["CompositeData"] = (
            from a in _db.Task.AsEnumerable()
            join b in _db.Product on a.ProductId equals b.ProductId
            select new MyViewModel
            {
                TaskId = a.TaskId,
                TaskDesc = a.TaskDescription,
                ProdDesc = b.ProductDescription
            }).ToList();
```

and in the view, you need to cast to this view model collection.

```
@foreach (var item in ViewData["CompositeData"] as List<TomFoolery.Models.MyViewModel>)
{
   <p>@item.TaskId</p>
}
```

You may also consider eliminating the use of ViewData and go for a complete strongly typed view model approach. Create a view model for your view for that

```
public class MyPageViewModel
{
  public List<MyViewModel> Tasks {set;get;}
  public List<Product> Products {set;get;}
}
```

and in your GET action, instead of setting to ViewData, create an object of this view model and set to it's corresponding properties

```
var vm = new MyPageViewModel();
vm.Products = _db.Product.ToList();
vm.Tasks = (
                from a in _db.Task.AsEnumerable()
                join b in _db.Product on a.ProductId equals b.ProductId
                select new MyViewModel
                {
                    TaskId = a.TaskId,
                    TaskDesc = a.TaskDescription,
                    ProdDesc = b.ProductDescription
                }).ToList();
return View(vm);
```

and in your view which is strongly typed to our new view model

```
@model MyPageViewModel
@foreach(var item in Model.Tasks)
{
  <p>@item.TaskId</p
  <p>@item.TaskDesc</p>
  <p>@item.ProdDesc</p>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ViewData["CompositeData"] = JoinTest;
```

`JoinTest` is an `IEnumerable<anonymous_type>`, therefore you can't cast it into a `List<TomFoolery.Models.ViewModel>`.

```
    var JoinTest = (
        from a in _db.Task.AsEnumerable()
        join b in _db.Product on a.ProductId equals b.ProductId
        select new TomFoolery.Models.ViewModel /* changed */
        {
            TaskId = a.TaskId,
            TaskDesc = a.TaskDescription,
            ProdDesc = b.ProductDescription
        });
    ViewData["CompositeData"] = JoinTest.ToList(); /*changed */
```

Comment: Do I have to edit the model or will this function without it?

Comment: It depends on the definition of `ViewModel` is the same as the anonymous type or not. If it is, it should work. Otherwise, do follow Shyju's answer.

Comment: Noted. Thanks for helping me out.